# Is it possible to pass some values from one stored procedure to another calling it along with the variable names?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
execute addNewItem @new, @KID, @EAN1, @namn, @pris, @Store,'';
```

I am trying to call a stored procedure `addNewItem`, from another stored procedure which uses a cursor with select. Each time the variables (`@new, @EAN, @KID, ...`) get their values processed, need to pass to this stored procedure `addNewItem`, when I check the tables seems that the operations are not done which were expected to be done by `addNewItem`. 
Am i doing some mistake here, saw [how to share data between store procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) but was difficult to understand at least for me. some help would be appreciable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. From your limited explanation it sounds like your code executes but doesn't give the results you expect. Have you traced the execution with SQL Profiler to see if the code is executing as you expect?

Comment: @Pondlife      Thanks for the hint on how to move ahead and the suggestion, I will go for it.